# Printing two TabPages on a TabControl in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, printing, tabpage

I am using Visual Studio express 2013, VB. Simplifying the problem as much as I can, I have a form with a tab control that has 2 tab pages. I want to print both tab pages on the click of one button. Currently I am trying to use CreateGraphics on the individual tabs but I just get the first tab printing on both pages. Here is my code, can anyone please see what I am doing wrong or if I am on completely the wrong lines. It looks to me like the CreateGraphics is not retrieving the right tabpages graphics.

```
Private Declare Auto Function BitBlt Lib "gdi32.dll" (ByVal hdcDest As IntPtr, ByVal nXDest As Integer, ByVal nYDest As Integer, ByVal nWidth As Integer, ByVal nHeight As Integer, ByVal hdcSrc As IntPtr, ByVal nXSrc As Integer, ByVal nYSrc As Integer, ByVal dwRop As System.Int32) As Boolean
Private Const SRCCOPY As Integer = &HCC0020
Private PagePrinting As Integer

Private Sub ToolStripButton2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ToolStripButton2.Click
    If PrintDialog1.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
        PagePrinting = 0
        PrintDocument1.Print()
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub PrintDocument1_PrintPage(sender As Object, e As PrintPageEventArgs) Handles PrintDocument1.PrintPage
    If PagePrinting = 0 Then
        e.Graphics.DrawImage(GetImage1(), e.MarginBounds)
    Else
        e.Graphics.DrawImage(GetImage2(), e.MarginBounds)
    End If
    PagePrinting = PagePrinting + 1
    If PagePrinting = 2 Then e.HasMorePages = False Else e.HasMorePages = True
End Sub

Private Function GetImage1() As Bitmap
    Dim me_gr As Graphics = Me.BillTabControl.TabPages("PAGE1").CreateGraphics
    Dim bm As New Bitmap(Me.BillTabControl.TabPages("PAGE1").ClientSize.Width, Me.BillTabControl.TabPages("PAGE1").ClientSize.Height, me_gr)
    Dim bm_gr As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bm)
    Dim bm_hdc As IntPtr = bm_gr.GetHdc
    Dim me_hdc As IntPtr = me_gr.GetHdc
    BitBlt(bm_hdc, 0, 0, Me.BillTabControl.TabPages("PAGE1").ClientSize.Width, Me.BillTabControl.TabPages("PAGE1").ClientSize.Height, me_hdc, 0, 0, SRCCOPY)
    me_gr.ReleaseHdc(me_hdc)
    bm_gr.ReleaseHdc(bm_hdc)
    GetImage1 = bm
End Function

Private Function GetImage2() As Bitmap
    Dim me_gr As Graphics = Me.BillTabControl.TabPages("PAGE2").CreateGraphics
    Dim bm As New Bitmap(Me.BillTabControl.TabPages("PAGE2").ClientSize.Width, Me.BillTabControl.TabPages("PAGE2").ClientSize.Height, me_gr)
    Dim bm_gr As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bm)
    Dim bm_hdc As IntPtr = bm_gr.GetHdc
    Dim me_hdc As IntPtr = me_gr.GetHdc
    BitBlt(bm_hdc, 0, 0, Me.BillTabControl.TabPages("PAGE2").ClientSize.Width, Me.BillTabControl.TabPages("PAGE2").ClientSize.Height, me_hdc, 0, 0, SRCCOPY)
    me_gr.ReleaseHdc(me_hdc)
    bm_gr.ReleaseHdc(bm_hdc)
    GetImage2 = bm
End Function
```

Comment: You cannot call CreateGraphics() on an unselected tab.  You'll have to select it first and call the TabPage.Update() method to ensure it finished painting.  Do consider using the TabPage.DrawToBitmap() method instead.

Comment: I tried that it doesn't work. I think the problem might be that I have already initiated the Printing, so selecting the tab just doesn't seem to work. It works fine if I split the pages into 2 separate PrintDocument1.Print() lines (not what I want at all). I will keep playing around with it and if I find an answer I will post it here. I'll try DrawToBitmap first. Thanks both.

Comment: Yes, DrawToBitmap works. The code in the two GetImage subs is now...Sorted, thank you very much. The code is simpler than CreateGraphics, I have just changed the two GetImage subs. The tabpages do not need to be selected for this to work. Code looks ugly here I'll post it in 8 hours when I'm allowed, I'm not reputable enough yet.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried selecting the second tab before creating the graphics with [`SelectTab`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c881zk4f(v=vs.110).aspx)?

You may also want to add a breakpoint to this line to make sure it is being called:
`e.Graphics.DrawImage(GetImage2(), e.MarginBounds)`

Comment: Yes I have, it didn't work so I took it out - but just to be sure I put it in again and it still doesn't work. And I've tried breakpoints everywhere, that's why there are two GetImage Subs, I tried one passing in the page then split them out to see if that isolated the problem more. No luck. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code that works.

```
Private Function GetImage1() As Bitmap
    Dim bm As New Bitmap(Me.BillTabControl.TabPages("PAGE1").ClientSize.Width, Me.BillTabControl.TabPages("PAGE1").ClientSize.Height)
    Me.BillTabControl.TabPages("PAGE1").DrawToBitmap(bm, Me.BillTabControl.TabPages("PAGE1").ClientRectangle)
    GetImage1 = bm
End Function

Private Function GetImage2() As Bitmap
    Dim bm As New Bitmap(Me.BillTabControl.TabPages("PAGE2").ClientSize.Width, Me.BillTabControl.TabPages("PAGE2").ClientSize.Height)
    Me.BillTabControl.TabPages("PAGE2").DrawToBitmap(bm, Me.BillTabControl.TabPages("PAGE2").ClientRectangle)
    GetImage2 = bm
End Function
```